# JAX-metal installation on M2 Mac fails

Tags: python, apple-m1, jax

I am trying to install `jax` with metal GPU support, following the [Apple developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/metal/jax/). It fails at the point of installing `jaxlib` from source with at the specified version due to something missing for linking.

*While this may relate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76979869/9887971), in my case I have verified that I am not using an x86 python installation, but the correct arm64 one.*

The following succeeds

```
python3 -m venv ~/jax-metal
source ~/jax-metal/bin/activate
python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip install numpy wheel
git clone https://github.com/google/jax.git --branch jaxlib-v0.4.10 --single-branch
cd jax
```

And then

```
python build/build.py --bazel_options=--@xla//xla/python:enable_tpu=true
```

fails essentially on (see full output below)

```
dyld[33851]: symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZNKSt3_V214error_category10_M_messageB5cxx11Ei'
```

I am on an M2 Pro MacMini, with Ventura 13.5.2 and `homebrew` Python 3.11.5, and gcc (Homebrew GCC 13.1.0) 13.1.0 which is the one I suppose it's using for installation.

Full output:

```
Downloading bazel from: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/5.1.1/bazel-5.1.1-darwin-arm64
bazel-5.1.1-darwin-arm64 [########################################] 100%
Bazel binary path: ./bazel-5.1.1-darwin-arm64
Bazel version: 5.1.1
Python binary path: /Users/tks32/jax-metal/bin/python
Python version: 3.11
NumPy version: 1.25.2
MKL-DNN enabled: yes
Target CPU: arm64
Target CPU features: release
CUDA enabled: no
TPU enabled: no
ROCm enabled: no
Plugin device enabled: no

Building XLA and installing it in the jaxlib source tree...
./bazel-5.1.1-darwin-arm64 run --verbose_failures=true :build_wheel -- --output_path=/Users/tks32/tmp/jax/dist --cpu=arm64
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=0 --terminal_columns=80
INFO: Reading rc options for 'run' from /Users/tks32/tmp/jax/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'common' options: --experimental_repo_remote_exec
INFO: Reading rc options for 'run' from /Users/tks32/tmp/jax/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --nocheck_visibility --apple_platform_type=macos --macos_minimum_os=10.14 --announce_rc --define open_source_build=true --spawn_strategy=standalone --enable_platform_specific_config --experimental_cc_shared_library --define=no_aws_support=true --define=no_gcp_support=true --define=no_hdfs_support=true --define=no_kafka_support=true --define=no_ignite_support=true --define=grpc_no_ares=true --define=tsl_link_protobuf=true -c opt --config=short_logs --copt=-DMLIR_PYTHON_PACKAGE_PREFIX=jaxlib.mlir. --@xla//xla/python:enable_gpu=false --@xla//xla/python:enable_tpu=false --@xla//xla/python:enable_plugin_device=false
INFO: Reading rc options for 'run' from /Users/tks32/tmp/jax/.jax_configure.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --strategy=Genrule=standalone --repo_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/Users/tks32/jax-metal/bin/python --action_env=PYENV_ROOT --python_path=/Users/tks32/jax-metal/bin/python --distinct_host_configuration=false --@xla//xla/python:enable_tpu=true --config=mkl_open_source_only
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:short_logs in file /Users/tks32/tmp/jax/.bazelrc: --output_filter=DONT_MATCH_ANYTHING
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:mkl_open_source_only in file /Users/tks32/tmp/jax/.bazelrc: --define=tensorflow_mkldnn_contraction_kernel=1
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:macos in file /Users/tks32/tmp/jax/.bazelrc: --config=posix
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:posix in file /Users/tks32/tmp/jax/.bazelrc: --copt=-fvisibility=hidden --copt=-Wno-sign-compare --cxxopt=-std=c++17 --host_cxxopt=-std=c++17
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_tks32/fc3829a9a8c5115880c7fe02f687024b/external/xla/third_party/repo.bzl:132:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'tf_runtime' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_tks32/fc3829a9a8c5115880c7fe02f687024b/external/xla/third_party/repo.bzl:132:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'llvm-raw' because it already exists.
Loading:
Loading: 1 packages loaded
Analyzing: target //build:build_wheel (2 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //build:build_wheel (35 packages loaded, 11 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //build:build_wheel (178 packages loaded, 6164 targets configured)
INFO: Analyzed target //build:build_wheel (202 packages loaded, 14602 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
[0 / 18] [Prepa] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt ... (6 actions, 0 running)
[77 / 196] Compiling llvm/lib/Support/VirtualFileSystem.cpp; 2s local ... (10 actions, 9 running)
[147 / 196] Compiling llvm/lib/Support/FileUtilities.cpp; 0s local ... (9 actions, 8 running)
[235 / 393] Compiling llvm/lib/TableGen/Record.cpp; 3s local ... (10 actions, 9 running)
[329 / 393] Compiling llvm/lib/Support/YAMLParser.cpp; 1s local ... (10 actions, 9 running)
[683 / 3,072] Compiling llvm/lib/Support/VirtualFileSystem.cpp; 1s local ... (10 actions, 9 running)
[916 / 3,493] Compiling jaxlib/cpu/lapack.cc; 0s local ... (10 actions, 9 running)
[1,219 / 3,783] Compiling src/idl_gen_ts.cpp; 2s local ... (10 actions, 9 running)
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_tks32/fc3829a9a8c5115880c7fe02f687024b/external/llvm-project/llvm/BUILD.bazel:1153:7: Generating code from table: lib/Target/RISCV/RISCV.td @llvm-project//llvm:RISCVTargetParserDefGen__gen_riscv_target_def_genrule failed: (Aborted): bash failed: error executing command
  (cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_tks32/fc3829a9a8c5115880c7fe02f687024b/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    PATH='/Users/tks32/jax-metal/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/util-linux/sbin:/opt/homebrew/opt/util-linux/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Users/tks32/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts' \
  /bin/bash -c 'source external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh; bazel-out/darwin_arm64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/llvm/llvm-min-tblgen -I external/llvm-project/llvm/include -I external/llvm-project/clang/include -I $(dirname external/llvm-project/llvm/lib/Target/RISCV/RISCV.td) -gen-riscv-target-def external/llvm-project/llvm/lib/Target/RISCV/RISCV.td  -o bazel-out/darwin_arm64-opt-exec-50AE0418/bin/external/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/TargetParser/RISCVTargetParserDef.inc')
# Configuration: 473e1790c1163373bc4b413765265c68088f71ecbdf7b8c4a3008300a9ff0cff
# Execution platform: @local_execution_config_platform//:platform
dyld[33851]: symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZNKSt3_V214error_category10_M_messageB5cxx11Ei'
/bin/bash: line 1: 33851 Abort trap: 6           bazel-out/darwin_arm64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/llvm/llvm-min-tblgen -I external/llvm-project/llvm/include -I external/llvm-project/clang/include -I $(dirname external/llvm-project/llvm/lib/Target/RISCV/RISCV.td) -gen-riscv-target-def external/llvm-project/llvm/lib/Target/RISCV/RISCV.td -o bazel-out/darwin_arm64-opt-exec-50AE0418/bin/external/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/TargetParser/RISCVTargetParserDef.inc
Target //build:build_wheel failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 82.156s, Critical Path: 5.18s
INFO: 1229 processes: 531 internal, 698 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
ERROR: Build failed. Not running target
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
b''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tks32/tmp/jax/build/build.py", line 564, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/tks32/tmp/jax/build/build.py", line 559, in main
    shell(command)
  File "/Users/tks32/tmp/jax/build/build.py", line 53, in shell
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 466, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 571, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['./bazel-5.1.1-darwin-arm64', 'run', '--verbose_failures=true', ':build_wheel', '--', '--output_path=/Users/tks32/tmp/jax/dist', '--cpu=arm64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: What c++filt said about symbol?